# ClaimsPrincipal not working on IIS - Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, iis, authorization, claims

Why does this code work locally when I run the program in Visual Studio (IIS Express) but not on IIS?

Error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

```
var userName = claim.Subject.Name
```

Controller:

```
ClaimsPrincipal principal = HttpContext.User as ClaimsPrincipal;

var claim = principal.Claims.FirstOrDefault();
var userName = claim.Subject.Name;
string[] Name = userName.Split("\\");
```

I tried other solutions too, but nothing works for IIS.

**Startup.cs**

```
app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();

 services
        .AddAuthentication(NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddNegotiate();
 services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
```

ClaimsTransformer.cs(works)

```
     public Task<ClaimsPrincipal> TransformAsync(ClaimsPrincipal principal)
    {
        try
        {
            var claiminfo = (ClaimsIdentity)principal.Identity;
            string[] Name = claiminfo.Name.Split("\\");

            _service.SetUser(Name[1]);
            var role = _service.GetRoles(Name[1]);
            user = Name[1];
            var c = new Claim(claiminfo.RoleClaimType, role);
            claiminfo.AddClaim(c);
            return Task.FromResult(principal);
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Comment: How is your authentication configured? Looks like it isn't getting the claims to the user.

Comment: Do you have auth middleware configured properly?  `app.UseAuthentication()`